# Django Aggregate Max doesn't give correct max for CharField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this query to give me the next available key from the DB. It works just fine until it get to 10, where it will say that 10 is available when it's not

```
max_var = ShortUrl.objects.filter(is_custom=False).aggregate(max=Cast(Coalesce(Max('key'), 0),BigIntegerField()))['max'] + 1
```

The column is a CharField.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: The order is wrong.  You're calculating the alphabetical 'max' and then casting the result into a string.  You need to cast the row into an integer first and then calculate the max (not sure if you can, though).

Answer (score 1):

You need to **annotate**(cast string to int) first. Then you can find the **aggregate** of casted value. ie:

```
from django.db.models import BigIntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import Max

max_var = ShortUrl.objects.filter(is_custom=False) \
    .annotate(key_int = Cast('key', output_field=BigIntegerField())) \
    .aggregate(max=Max('key_int'))['max'] or 0

max_var+=1
```